# Find all characters in string with comma using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, rubular

I want to search all '2' s in the string below:

```
2, 10,11,1,1, 22,1,12,1,1, 1,2 , 2  ,2
```

---

I gave regular expression:

```
(^\s*(2)\s*)|(\s*,\s*(2)\s*(,|$))
```

But it **will not** search **last but one 2**.

---

I changed regular expression now as,

```
(^\s*(2)\s*)|(\s*,\s*(2)\s*)
```

But now it will take **one of the 2s in 22**.

---

How can I change the regular expression so that I find **all** the 2s (22 or 12 should **not** be considered)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match all the standalone `2` in the input string:

```
(?<!\d)2(?!\d)
```

The regex above is equivalent to the following regex, as in it will always have the same number of matches, and the content of the capturing group 1 in this regex is the same as the content matched by the other regex:

```
(?:^|\D)(2)(?:\D|$)
```

Note that (both) regex above doesn't care about the format of the input. It just simply extract any standalone 2, even in:

```
2 plain text, 2,43_2,lkjsf
^             ^    ^
```

---

If you want to match columns with the value `2`, and disregard `2` in `2 2` or `abc 2`:

```
(?:^|,) *(2) *(?=,|$)
```

It will match the only the `2` in this sample text:

```
2 plain text, 2 ,2, 43_2, 2 2,2   ,234,2
              ^  ^            ^        ^
```

Comment: If I "2,2 2,2" How can ignore 2 with space in between in the same regular expression

Comment: @SHRI: Your new requirement will invalidate all the answers here, so it belongs to a new question. It is your fault for not specifying all the details.

Comment: I did not specify because, it is a 'nice to have' requirement for me. That's why I still accepted your answer. Please provide if it not so complex

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead.

```
(?<!\d)2(?!\d)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC4qF9/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "2, 10,11,1,1, 22,1,12,1,1, 1,2 , 2  ,2"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\d)2(?!\d)', s)
['2', '2', '2', '2']
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\d)2` Lookbehind asserts that the `2` would be preceded by any but not a digit.
- `2(?!\d)` Asserts that the 2 must be followed by any but not of a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this is what you are looking for

```
 [^\d]2[^\d]
```

http://regex101.com/r/nD6nZ9/1

the python code must be something like

```
p = re.compile(ur'[^\d]2[^\d]', re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: This can't catch `2` at the beginning or at the end of the string.